# Deleting a non-existing identity in DynamoDB Golang

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I am having a golang project where I am using `dynamoDB` as my backend database. I wanted to return the error when we are trying to Delete a non-existing entity. But the `DynamoDB.DeleteItem` does not return an error on that thing. Please help me with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do it using the `response` you will get from `DeleteItem` method in dynamoDB.

Ex:

```golang
resp, err := dynamoDB.DeleteItem(input)
    if resp.ConsumedCapacity != nil {
        \\entity not found error
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the first struct returned by the [DeleteItem function](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb#Client.DeleteItem) is a [DeleteItemOutput](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb#DeleteItemOutput)

There's a comment that addresses how this object would be present

> This map appears in the response only if ReturnValues was specified as ALL_OLD in the request.

You can adjust your logic accordingly and it might solve your problem